# How to create a public event in a UserControl, that is reached from any of its component controls?

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, delegates

I'm doing this custom control, for selecting letters from a focusable `Panel`.

[image]

Each letter is selected on `MouseDown` event.

What I've been trying to do is to create an only public event, (and thus know when a letter, any, has been clicked), let's say `LetterClick` , which is reached with any call to `Letters_MouseDown`. With this code, the event is reached form client, but the application hangs.

```
public event MouseEventHandler LetterClick;

private void LettersPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var letter in collection)
    {
        // get all labels and suscribe each one to a single private event
        letter.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Letters_MouseDown);
    }

    // public event
    this.LetterClick += Letters_MouseDown;
}

private void Letters_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // ... container get focus, draw selected effect image, formatting,
    // set Letter property, etc...

    if (LetterClick != null)
    {
        LetterClick(sender, e);
    }
}

protected virtual void OnLetterClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventHandler handler = LetterClick;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(sender, e);
    }
}
```

From client:

```
lettersPanel1.LetterClick += new MouseEventHandler(lettersPanel1_LetterClick);

private void lettersPanel1_LetterClick(object sender, MouseDownEventArgs e)
{
    string letterSelected = myCustomControl1.Letter;
}
```

I think there is some kind of infinte looping here, but I'm pretty inexperienced about events and delegates, plus the MSDN documentation is not very clear for me yet.
If anyone can give me some help I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the error -

```
// public event
this.LetterClick += Letters_MouseDown;
```

It is subscribing to the event and then again calling itself recursively -

```
if (LetterClick != null)
{
    LetterClick(sender, e);
}
```

Remove the first line and it should be ok -

```
private void LettersPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var letter in collection)
    {
        // get all labels and suscribe each one to a single private event
        letter.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Letters_MouseDown);
    }

    // public event
    //this.LetterClick += Letters_MouseDown; //remove this line
}
```

**NOTE**: It is not a good idea to call the handlers directly, because it will hang the calling thread. So if the calling thread is the UI thread (for example a Click Event or a Load Event), it will be hanged until the process is completed.

A more better way would be to use `async` and `await`.

**EDIT**:

MSDN has a very good article on `async` and `await`. Try this link - [Walkthrough: Accessing the Web by Using Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx). But it is always possible to get intimidated by the feature easily, so make sure you read some good articles on `async` and `await` when you have time. Here is a good one -

[Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Letters_MouseDown` is a handler on `LetterClick`, then inside that method you invoke `LetterClick` again.

That's the infinite loop.